# How to get user information after login in laravel fortify

Tags: laravel-fortify

I am using laravel fortify in my single page vue application. When i send XHR request to `sitePath + '/login'` i get `{two_factor: false}` in response and user is logged in. How can i add user information so i can save the data in local storage.

```
let response = await this.$root.requestPost(data, url);
async requestPost(data, requestUrl) {
    const response = await axios.post(requestUrl, {
        // ...data
    }).catch(error => {
        //
    });
    return response;
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for late answer.

But today I have solved same problem.

In FortifyServiceProvider's register() method, you need implement own LoginResponse:

```
$this->app->instance(LoginResponse::class, new class implements LoginResponse {
        public function toResponse($request)
        {
            /**
             * @var User $user
             */
            $user = $request->user();
            return $request->wantsJson()
                ? response()->json(['two_factor' => false, 'email' => $user->email ])
                : redirect()->intended(Fortify::redirects('login'));
        }
    });
```

Documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#customizing-authentication-redirects